# Convert string array values to hash optimally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get a ruby hash that looks like

```
{:sunday=>"sunday", :monday=>"monday", :tuesday=>"tuesday", :wednesday=>"wednesday", :thursday=>"thursday", :friday=>"friday", :saturday=>"saturday"}
```

(the purpose for this weird looking hash is to use it as string enums in rails ActiveRecord model)

the way I have done the same is:

```
Hash[Date::DAYNAMES.map {|x| [x.downcase.to_sym,x.downcase]}]
```

Is there a more optimal way for the same?
or a more ruby like way of doing so

Comment: Any reason for not using `MY_ENUM = {sunday: "sunday", monday: "monday", tuesday: "tuesday", wednesday: "wednesday", thursday: "thursday", friday:"friday", saturday: "saturday"}`? It is highly unlikely that the day names will change at any point such that you would need this to be dynamic and future proof.

Comment: @engineersmnky you're right. In my case. that is kinda ideal 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, the first I can think of is using `to_h` and pass a block (if your Ruby version implements it, if not, see Ursus' answer):

```
Date::DAYNAMES.map(&:downcase).to_h { |day| [day.to_sym, day] }
# => {:sunday=>"sunday", :monday=>"monday", :tuesday=>"tuesday", :wednesday=>"wednesday", :thursday=>"thursday", :friday=>"friday", :saturday=>"saturday"}
```

Another one is using `index_by`:

```
Date::DAYNAMES.map(&:downcase).index_by(&:to_sym)
# => {:sunday=>"sunday", :monday=>"monday", :tuesday=>"tuesday", :wednesday=>"wednesday", :thursday=>"thursday", :friday=>"friday", :saturday=>"saturday"}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's difficult do better. My try anyway

```
Date::DAYNAMES.map(&:downcase).map { |day| [day.to_sym, day] }.to_h
```